# How solve error 'Configuration result is immutable' using package loadtest with configfile?

Tags: load-testing, pm2

I would like to run [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) (command `npx loadtest http://localhost:3000/endpoint`) on production server with configuration file .loadtestrc:

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "body": {
        "to": "example@hotmail.com",
        "subject": "Loadtest",
        "text": "Loadtest text"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "maxRequests": 1,
    "concurrency": 1
  }
```

but that gives error 'Configuration result is immutable'.

How can I solve that?

Also tried running this from the command line:

```
loadtest https://localhost:3000/endpoint -c 1 -n 1 -H Accept:application/json -T application/json -P '{ "to": "example@hotmail.com", "subject": "Loadtest", "text": "Loadtest text" }' -m POST
```

but that gives the same error.

On the server Ubuntu is running with NGINX.